# Start right page below chapter heading on left page within xltabular

Tags: margins, koma-script, double-sided, xltabular, headline

I am trying to make a notation table using an xltabular. This spans a bit more than one page. I am using the class scrbook, where all my chapters start on an odd page. However, for the notation table, I find it more practical to start it on an even page, so that all the notation can be seen at once. I achieved this using `\KOMAoptions{open=any}`. The left-hand page starts with the chapter heading "Notation", followed by the first part of the table, and the table continues on the right-hand page. Currently, this part of the table starts much higher than the part below the chapter heading. Is there a possibility to introduce a larger upper margin for this page so that the heading continues at the same height? So what I am aiming at is something like

```
------------------------------  ------------------------------
|                            |  |                            |
|  Notation                  |  |                            |
|                            |  |                            |
| A bla                      |  | x bla                      |
| B bla                      |  | y bla                      |
 ...                              ...
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,usegeometry]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\geometry{tmargin=40mm,textheight=219mm,bindingoffset=5mm,textwidth=151.2mm}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline}
\title{My title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\mainmatter
\chapter{Usual chapter}

\KOMAoptions{open=any}
\backmatter
\chapter{Notation}
\begin{center}
 \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lX}
  Symbol & Usage \\\hline
  $A$ & Set of bla \\
  $\mathfrak B$ & Borel $\sigma$-algebra \\
  $C$ \footnotemark& bla \\
  $D$ & bla \\
  $\mathrm{CV}$ & Coefficient of variation \\
  $E$ & bla \\
  $F$ & bla \\
  $\delta^-$, $\delta^+$ & Incoming and outgoing arcs, respectively \\
  $\Delta$ & bla \\
  $\mathrm e$ & Euler constant \\
  $\mathrm E$ & Expected value \\
  $\varepsilon$ & Arbitrarily small positive constant \\
  $g$ & Function defined in ... \\
  $I$ & bla \\
  $J$ & bla \\
  $K$ & bla \\
  $L$ & Set of bla \\
  $L_i$ & bla \\
  $M$ & Number of bla \\
  $N$ \footnotemark[1] & Bla \\
  $n$ & Number of bla \\
  $O$ & Big Oh (Landau symbol) \\
  $p$ \footnotemark[1] & bla \\
  $\bar{p}$ & Expected bla \\
  $q$ \footnotemark[1] & bla \\
  $\bar{q}$ & Expected bla \\
  $\mathrm \Pi$ & bla \\
  $\Pr$ & Probability \\
  $r$ & bla \\
  $R$ & bla \\
  $\rho$ & bla \\
  $S$ \footnotemark[1] & bla \\
  $\mathrm S$ & bla \\
  $\mathrm S^{\mathrm p}$ & bla \\
  $T$ & bla \\
  $\mathrm{Var}$ & Variance \\
  $w$ & bla \\
  $\phi$ & Golden ratio \\
  $x$ & bla \\
  $y$ & bla \\
  $(\Omega,\mathfrak A,P)$ & Underlying probability space in stochastic scheduling \\
  $\mathrm \Omega$ & Big Omega (Landau symbol) \\\hline
 \end{xltabular}
\end{center}
\footnotetext{When printed in bold face, this is a random variable.}
\thispagestyle{plain}

Small text here
\KOMAoptions{open=right}


\end{document}
```